# Система цифровых ID

Tags: mongodb

Как можно сделать систему порядковых цифровых ID'ов? Чтобы каждый пользователь получал свой ID. Например, у первого пользователя ID - 1, у второго - 2, у третьего - 3, и т.д.

Comment: Вероятно написать код ;) А если без шуток, то чуть-чуть объясните, что вам нужно по четче в вопросе

Comment: Например, как в vk.com . У каждого нового пользователя - ID на 1 цифру больше, чем у прошлого. То есть, если зарегистрироваться 10, то твой ID будет 10, а если зарегистрироваться 1023, то твой ID будет 1023

Comment: Ну, если все пользователи у вас в нормальной БД, то там есть возможность включить автопроставление ID, если у вас все пользователи в файле записаны, то читать ID последнего пользователя и делать +1 у нового

Comment: А в MongoDB получится это сделать? Просто я не так давно с ней знаком и не знаю весь ее функционал

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384029/auto-increment-in-mongodb-to-store-sequence-of-unique-user-id

Answer (score 2):

вообще-то это не питон - это больше к вопросу о БД в которой вы будете хранить информацию о пользователях

там можно использовать `AUTO_INCREMENT` и при добавлении данных о пользователе в таблицу для нового пользователя будет выделяться новый `ID`

по идее если вы все делаете только в питоне - можно использовать тот же самый принцип:

есть хранилище данных о пользователях, номер записи - это и есть ID пользователя по которым можно найти информацию о нем:

условный код:

```
users_data = list()

def add_user(name):
    users_data.append(name)
    return len(users_data)
```